# Is it safe to share a KVM virtual disk between active / passive systems

Tags: kvm, disk-image

I have two VMs that run a DB2 database under a Linux guest OS.  Only one database will be active at a time, though I'd like both VMs to be running at the same time.

The database would be stored on a virtual disk image (thinking .img, but open to other formats) backed by a SAN and that disk image would be attached to both VMs

Is it safe to have the virtual disk file configured in each VM if the virtual disk is only mounted by the "active" machine?

Comment: Yes you can share the hard drive as long as the systems are compatible and not running at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I wound up doing in sharing a drive between VM1 and VM2

Create the shared file system

- `qemu-img create -f raw sharetest.img`
- Start VM1
- `virsh attach-disk VM1 <full-path-to-sharetest.img> vdb`
- login to VM1 as root, use gparted to put a file system on /dev/vdb (or mkfs)
- `mount /dev/vdb /mnt`
  At this point, you can read/write files to the shared drive using /mnt.

To move this file system do the following

- `umount /mnt`  to umount the file system from VM1
- `virsh detach-disk VM1 vdb`
- Start VM2
- `virsh attach-disk VM2 <full-path-to-sharetest.img> vdb`
- Log into VM2 and `mount /dev/vdb /mnt`

This works, I've moved the sharetest.img file back and forth between VM1 and VM2 many times.

Just out of curiosity, I decided to see what happens if I attached sharetest.img to both VMs at the same time.  I was thinking I'd attach it to both VMs and then just need to coordinate the mount / unmount commands.   Unfortunately, while I was able to use `virsh attach-disk` on both VMs to get it to attach, it caused an error with SELinux and KVM got really confused would't allow the guest OS to see the drive even though it listed the drive as being detached.  Even after detaching the drive from both systems if I tried to reattach the drive again it would say that vdb was already in use.

In summary, as long as you're careful about ensuring the disk is only attached to one VM at a time, it's fine to share a disk between VMs.

Answer (score 1):

Well the problem is if the `active` system mess up the database then your `passive` system won't do any good.